# PHP Set Cookies in MD5

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I have an application script, where people can apply for our clan.

Is it possible, to generate a random string, convert this string to an `md5`, save it in a `DB` to the users application and also set this MD5 as a cookie for the applier.

If the Applier goes e.g. to `"applicationstatus.php"` that he only sees his own application with this cookie? 
And if he doesn't have a cookie, which is in the DB he gets an error screen

Regards

Comment: What's the point of passing the random string through the MD5 algorithm?

Comment: Why tie something like this so closely to a cookie (which could get deleted and won't exist across multiple browsers used by the same person)? Why not just have a proper login instead?

Comment: it's more secure in my eyes. I think its no big deal to hash it?

Comment: Have you got an example of some code you have already tried?

Comment: @user3544246 — How is it more secure? You're just trading a random string (which contains no information, it is just an identifier) for an MD5 representation of it. At best you achieve nothing, at worse you run into collisions.

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far.

Quentin, you are right. I didn't think of that ^^

Comment: Yeah, i will forget that idea